# Disable popup from Google Speech

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, speech-to-text

I want to disable the popup from Google Speech. I want it to run in the background so no popup should come up. I am programming in Visual Studio with c# and i want to make a Speech Recognition App on/in Android.

[I downloaded the sample code from the Xamarin page](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/PlatformFeatures/SpeechToText/)

Code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // set the isRecording flag to false (not recording)
    isRecording = false;

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // get the resources from the layout
    recButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord);
    textBox = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textYourText);


    // check to see if we can actually record - if we can, assign the event to the button
    string rec = Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureMicrophone;
    if (rec != "android.hardware.microphone")
    {
        // no microphone, no recording. Disable the button and output an alert
        var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(recButton.Context);
        alert.SetTitle("You don't seem to have a microphone to record with");
        alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, e) =>
        {
            textBox.Text = "No microphone present";
            recButton.Enabled = false;
            return;
        });

        alert.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        recButton.Click += delegate
        {
            // change the text on the button
            recButton.Text = "End Recording";
            isRecording = !isRecording;
            if (isRecording)
            {
                // create the intent and start the activity
                var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);

                // put a message on the modal dialog
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, Application.Context.GetString(Resource.String.messageSpeakNow));

                // if there is more then 1.5s of silence, consider the speech over
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.German);


                // you can specify other languages recognised here, for example

                // if you wish it to recognise the default Locale language and German
                // if you do use another locale, regional dialects may not be recognised very well

                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
                StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);
            }
        };
    }
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultVal, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == VOICE)
    {
        if (resultVal == Result.Ok)
        {
            var matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
            if (matches.Count != 0)
            {
                string textInput = textBox.Text + matches[0];

                // limit the output to 500 characters
                if (textInput.Length > 500)
                    textInput = textInput.Substring(0, 500);
                textBox.Text = textInput;
            }
            else
                textBox.Text = "No speech was recognised";
            // change the text back on the button
            recButton.Text = "Start Recording";
        }
    }
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultVal, data);
}
```

Can someone help me to disable the popup?

Comment: I'm sorry it's my fault. I mean that the popup shouldn't come up so if I press on the button it should start to listen(without popup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `SpeechRecognizer` for your app. The implementation of this API is likely to stream audio to remote servers to perform speech recognition.

Your app needs to have the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission.

For example:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, IRecognitionListener
{
    private TextView tv;
    private SpeechRecognizer sr;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        sr = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this);
        sr.SetRecognitionListener(this);

        Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
        btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, "this package");
            intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 5);
            sr.StartListening(intent);
        };

        tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
    }

    public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
        tv.Text = "Beginning";
    }

    public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
    }

    public void OnEndOfSpeech()
    {
    }

    public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
    {
        tv.Text = error.ToString();
    }

    public void OnEvent(int eventType, Bundle @params)
    {
    }

    public void OnPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {
    }

    public void OnReadyForSpeech(Bundle @params)
    {
        tv.Text = "Ready!";
    }

    public void OnResults(Bundle results)
    {
        var data = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(data[i]);
        }
        tv.Text = builder.ToString();
    }

    public void OnRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {
    }
}
```

This still uses google's speech service, if your device/ region doesn't support this service, you will need to find other speech services and use their API in your app.